# asp.net mvc post model and specify hour

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, datetime

Hi I ahve a model and it has Datetime typed property. When I post the form the hour of the date property hour should be 23:59. Which way is make sense.

- Creating a custom model binder
- Update date in action method
- I am using jQuery datetimepicker and its format is mm.dd.yy it not include hours.

  ```
  [Authorize, HttpPost]
  public ActionResult Edit(int? id, OrderFormViewModel formModel)
  {
      var model = repository.GetShippingsById(id.Value);

      if (TryUpdateModel(model, "Order"))
      {
          model.Date = new DateTime(formModel.Order.Date.Year, formModel.Order.Date.Month, formModel.Order.Date.Day, 23, 59, 59);

          repository.Save();
          return RedirectToAction("Details", new { @id = model.Id });
      }

      return View(formModel);
  }
  ```

Comment: If it is a requirement of the model, then put it in the setter of the date field.

Answer (score 0):

If problem only that you want to add hour(and hour is constant value), you can use ActionFilterAttribute, and on step of binding set hours, so in this case in your actin you will get correct value of date.

If you use custom form submitting you can update value via JS, but in this case you should pay attention at localization(of cause if it is important).

So in my opinion ActionFilterAttribute is better way.

But if you can update model, you can create property like:

```
private DateTime _date 
public DateTime Date{
  set{
   this._date = value; 
    //ADD CODE TO ADD HOURS
   }
  get{return _date ;}
}
```

Comment: but the object is in entity framework. is possible set it in partial class?

Comment: You can add function into partial class, that will return your date with hours. And you can create extention for dateTime type, that will get date with hour  public static Datetime AddHours(this DateTime d) {
        // Add hours
    };

Answer (score 0):

I would use your second option - update in action.
Reasons:

- it logically belongs to controller (view should have no calculations other than view related)
- its much simpler to do in C#
- its more straightforward & easier to maintain

But as usual, there's no right answer to your question. Up to usability, maintainability, easy of understanding ... you know the rest...

Hope this helps.